# How to use the values in a Confirmation Box in JavaScript perform a function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a confirmation box that appears when a specific option of a radio button is answered to either perform a subsequent system function or not, depending on whether they click '`confirm`' or '`no`'.

I can get the box to appear using this code:

```
let errors = [];
let radiobutton = form.getAnswerText("sIsPersonLongTermNeeds");

if (radiobutton == "sIsPersonLongTermNeedsNo" ||
    radiobutton == "sIsPersonLongTermNeedsUnknown"
) {
    window.confirm("text");
}
```

But I don't know how to use the values (which I believe are true/false)?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly = in the end? Redirect to another page? Reload the page? Show something to the user?

Comment: If confirm/okay is answered the it will set the answer of the rest of form page to null - I can do this based on the radio button answer, but I need to create a confirm box so that the user does not erroneously lose their work